# How do disable link with hash in Angular JS routing?

Tags: angularjs

I have some links on page with empty `href` param:

```
<a href="#">Link</a>
```

When I click on this link the page is reloaded on `www.bob.com/#`. How I can disable it in `$routeProvider`?

Comment: why don't you write `href="#/"` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead use:

```
<a href="#/">Link</a>
```

Comment: Glad to help @Faud. Please feel free to ask your doubts else mark it as an answer so that it won't appear as unanswered to others.